# Example using "doing" as an auxiliary verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

My textbook lists the forms of "do" including "doing" as auxiliary/helping verbs. I can't think of any example where it would be used as such. Can you?

Comment: What are you **doing asking** such a question?  What are you **doing to find** an answer to this through personal research?

Comment: @Cargill you are using the word as the main verb not the auxiliary/helping verb

Comment: No, I can't think of any, either.

Comment: And to see that user18967 is right about Cargill's comment, note that neither instance of "doing" is followed by a plain verb, as is the case when "do" is used as an auxiliary.

Answer (score 1):

No, I can't. I think your textbook is wrong. We don't use "do support" where there is another auxiliary, so the "do" only appears in the finite forms "do", "does" or "did".

Comment: And of course the negatives "don't," "doesn't" and "didn't."